# Large downloads failing on Apache

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I'm using fcgi with Apache and am having a problem serving .zip files to my members for downloading.

A 700MB file will start to download and then will fail after about 9 minutes (540 seconds) if not completed by then.

I checked my.cnf, php.ini and http.conf and couldn't find any timeout settings that were around this 540 second mark. I couldn't locate a fast cgi configuration file so no idea where that is or if it's the problem.

Could someone help me?

Thank you! - Jennifer

Comment: what do the logs say?

Comment: Where would I view the logs?

Comment: well its your server, i dont know how its set up.

Comment: i would start with Apache error logs ... typically at /var/log/apache2/error.log  though as noted it is your server and dont know how its set up

Comment: Okay, I think I found it. The only thing related to this domain in the error log is:

`[Sun Nov 10 13:45:53 2013] [warn] [client xx.175.228.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://----------.com/members/member
[Sun Nov 10 13:45:53 2013] [warn] [client xx.175.228.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, referer: http://------------.com/members/member`

Comment: research suggests setting `FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidIOTimeout    600` may help

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know of a way I could locate my fcgi configuration file? I'm having a really hard time finding it.

Comment: Not sure if this is where I would add those busytimeout settings: 
`# This file was automatically generated by the Cpanel PHP Configuration system
# If you wish to change the way PHP is being handled by Apache on your system,
# use the /usr/local/cpanel/bin/rebuild_phpconf script or the WHM interface.
#
# Manual edits of this file will be lost when Apache is updated.


# Fastcgi configuration for PHP5
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
MaxRequestsPerProcess 500

# End of autogenerated PHP configuration.
`

Comment: Have you found a way to fix this problem? I'm having the same right now!